# XML serialization to object collection

Tags: xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I want to serialize an xml string into collection of objects, but I can get get only first object. If I add more objects in xml, then it errors out. Not sure what I am missing. I tried declaring type as Emp[]

Here are my both "Emp" xml strings

```
string empsworking = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Emp><EmpInfo><Code>vv</Code><FirstName>van</FirstName><LastName>sa</LastName><Destination>sc</Destination></EmpInfo><EmpInfo><Code>rr</Code><FirstName>ro</FirstName><LastName>sa</LastName><Destination>ph</Destination></EmpInfo></Emp>";

         string empsNotworking = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Emp><EmpInfo><Code>vv</Code><FirstName>van</FirstName><LastName>sa</LastName><Destination>sc</Destination></EmpInfo></Emp>";
```

My classes look like

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Emp
{
    /// <remarks/>
   public EmpInfo EmpInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}

/// <remarks/>
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "EmpInfo")] 
public class EmpInfo
{

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Code;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FirstName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string LastName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Destination;
}
```

and my code to serialize is

```
           StringReader stream = null;
       XmlTextReader reader = null;
        Emp empprofile;
       try
       {
           // serialise to object
           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Emp));
           stream = new StringReader(emps); // read xml data
           reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);  // create reader
           // covert reader to object
           empprofile = (Emp)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (stream != null) stream.Close();
           if (reader != null) reader.Close();
       }
```

I can only read/get object with empworking.
How can get it as collection of "EmpInfo"? Please guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SerializeTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SerializeEmpTest()
    {
        EmpCollection empCollection = new EmpCollection()
            {
                new EmpInfo() {Code = "1", FirstName = "Anita"}, 
                new EmpInfo() {Code = "1", FirstName = "Johan"}
            };
        string xmlString = empCollection.GetXmlString();
    }
}

[XmlType, XmlRoot]
public class EmpCollection : List<EmpInfo>
{

}

[XmlType]
public class EmpInfo
{
    public string Code;

    public string FirstName;

}

public static class Extenstion
{
    public static string GetXmlString<T>(this T objectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string xml;
        using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder)))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, objectToSerialize);
            xml = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: your class definitions worked like a charm and I was able to get a list of EmpInfo objects. I did not have to change seriazation code. Thank you! How can I take it to the next level? I mean can I read nested object collection. For example if I want Contact as collection in EmpInfo.

Comment: <Emp>
  <EmpInfo>
    <Code>vv</Code>
    <FirstName>van</FirstName>
    <LastName>sa</LastName>
    <Destination>sc</Destination>
    <Contact>
      <HomePhone>888</HomePhone>
      <CellPhone>999</CellPhone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <HomePhone>99</HomePhone>
      <CellPhone>999</CellPhone>
    </Contact>
  </EmpInfo>
  <EmpInfo>
    <Code>rr</Code>
    <FirstName>ro</FirstName>
    <LastName>sa</LastName>
    <Destination>ph</Destination>
    <Contact>
      <HomePhone>888</HomePhone>
      <CellPhone>999</CellPhone>
    </Contact>
  </EmpInfo>
</Emp>

Comment: above is the xml for what I meant. Not a perfect example from data standpoint, but this is the structure. and Contact will be another class.

Comment: This is going to be too lengthy to have in comments I think. If I understand correctly the sample I posted above does what you want if you make Contacts a List<Contact>

Comment: yes...I am somewhat confused with
   public class EmpInfo
    {
        public EmpInfo()
        {
            Contacts= new List<EmpInfo>();
        }
        public string Code;
 
        public string FirstName;
 
        public List<EmpInfo> Contacts { get; set; }
 
    }
I had tried public List<Contact> Contact { get; set; } but Contact do not get populated.

Comment: I had to add <Contacts> as the parent element of <Contact> in my xml. Thanks a lot!